# What is iteration over placeholder in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator

I got the following (pseudo) code [from doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent):

```
words_in_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [time_steps, batch_size, num_features])
...
for current_batch_of_words in words_in_dataset:
```

But how can we iterate over placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you have [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager) which essentially evaluates things on the fly. In your case, that is just pseudo code albeit a misleading one that simply hints at how the algorithm goes over batches in the given word dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is only applicable in Session Graph mode. They are not available in Eager mode, it does not make sense. Placeholders are used to feed tensors to the graph because you don't build a graph, you don't need a placeholder in the first place.

As far as Iterating over the Placeholder is concerned and that pseudo code is concerned, the pseudo code only shows the algorithm, that we will implement.

To iterate over a placeholder, you will do something like this :

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[5])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(5):
        print(sess.run(X[i], feed_dict={X : [1,2,3,4,5]}))
```

Then the output will be :

> 1.0
>
> 2.0
>
> 3.0
>
> 4.0
>
> 5.0

The slicing rule is same as numpy arrays.